# Splitting string with multiple parameters

Tags: python

I have a string

```
Best product25.075.0Product29.029.0
```

And now I need to split this string to

```
'Best product' '25.0' '75.0' , 'Product' '29.0' '29.0'
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: `"25.075.0"` is inherently ambiguous, though. Is it `"25.0", "75.0"` or `"25.07", "5.0"`? You need to assume that each number has exactly one place after the decimal point for any of the answers to work. It would be better if you could modify whatever produces that string to use a separating character.

Comment: this string is just output, so i presented as it is. and it's "25.0", "75.0"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to find all words (containing letter or space - matching pattern `[a-zA-Z ]+`) or all numbers (one or more digits followd by a dot and zero - matching pattern `\d+.0`)

```
string = 'Best product25.075.0Product29.029.0'
import re
re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z ]+|\d+(?:.0)?', string)
# ['Best product', '25.0', '75.0', 'Product', '29.0', '29.0']
```

Comment: note that this will only work if the "words" dont contain any numbers

Comment: Than it will be a problem

Comment: @HeinerFrüh Updated the answer to work with words containing numbers without decimal points

Answer (score 2):

A very similar way to do it is:

```
import re
string = 'Best product25.075.0Product29.029.0'
re.findall(r'[^\d]+|\d+.0', string)
```

The code only distinguishes between non-digits `[^\d]+` and digits plus dot zero `\d+.0'`. So it matches also additional characters like `_`.